# In the Alternative Universe, why didn't Charming rescue Fiona?

Tags: shrek, shrek-forever-after

In [Shrek: Forever After](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0892791/), Fiona said she rescued *herself* from the dragon's tower.

**Since Shrek was never born, shouldn't Prince Charming have rescued her?**

Comment: After all, there was the deal between King Harold and Fairy Godmother.

Comment: Charming is an imbecile. He probably died like all the other would-be rescuers before him.

Comment: @Richard: Charming was stupid, but not a coward or useless. He displayed his political acumen and charisma quite clearly in *Shrek 3*, when he successfully incited the denizens of *The Ugly Step-Sister* to help him launch a coup in Far, Far Away. He also successfully seduces Rapunzel and captures Shrek and Fiona. The man was a buffoon, but he displayed more acumen than most modern politicians, and was a decent military leader. I've often wondered about user35971's question myself; Charming isn't the type to let his potential kingdom slip away.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - He was a total fool. He should have killed the hostages (and the dragon) when he had the opportunity. That's the difference between a kids movie and real life (or Game of Thrones)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At the start of *Shrek : Forever After* we see that Fiona's parents are about to sign their kingdom over to Rumpelstiltskin in return for him using his magic to release Princess Fiona from her curse. The news that Shrek has rescued the Princess literally interrupts the signing ceremony and they tear up the agreement.

Since Prince Charming is attempting to rescue Fiona for the sole purpose of becoming heir to the throne of Far Far Away, if Shrek hadn't rescued Fiona then her parents would have signed the deed, Rumpelstiltskin would become King and there would have been **no need for Charming to rescue Fiona** which explains his total absence from the film:

> **King :** *Nothing is worth more to us than our daughter.*
>
> **Stiltskin:** *Just sign it and all your problems will disappear.*
>
> **Page** : *Your Highness! The Princess! She's been saved! [by Shrek]*
>
> **They tear the agreement in half.**

Comment: That's a decent answer, and the closest we'll get to a correct one, but I don't buy the fact that Prince Charming - nor his mother - would stand by and allow a little thing like legality keep him from the throne of Far, Far Away. It's hard to believe that Charming, the man who launched a successful - if brief - coup against Shrek, wouldn't do the same against Rumpelstiltskin, especially with his mother's resources still available to him.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - But why rescue Princess Fiona if she's no longer in line to the throne? After they sign the deed, she's just a.n.other woman, albeit a stonking hottie.

Comment: Being a stonking hottie isn't reason enough? Any claim on the throne is better than none, legal or otherwise. You gain too much badboy for attacking with no *casus belli*.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - Fiona *does* enjoy Pina Coladas and walks in the rain. I'd be personally tempted to rescue her but we've no idea what Charming's motivations are. There's no suggestion that he can't attract hotties as needed.

Comment: He did tap Rapunzel. Still, one can never have too many hotties.

Answer (score -1):

I honestly think it was just a plot hole. The reality is that Fairy godmother had a deal with Harold. One that if he broke, his happily every after (his human form) would be taken back as well. Not to mention, they were still the rightful rulers.

And with the time frame as it was when this was happening, Charming was already on his way to save Fiona. He was just a tad bit late. I’d say a couple months late if not less as when he got there, Fiona was on her honeymoon.

Some people might say that he would have heard about the change in leadership before he saved her. But no not necessarily; Fiona had her whole identity and inner beauty shtick journey, got married to Shrek, went on her honeymoon and traveled to Far far away and Charming didn’t know ANYTHING about it. Not until he literally arrives at the castle and there’s a wolf in the bed who tells him she’s on her honeymoon last he heard.

So if Shrek never saved her and they did sign away, Charming should have gotten to Fiona and rescued her. Charming may be stupid but once he learns something is wrong, he most likely would have fought for what he believed was his right to the kingdom. And as we saw...he’s more than capable of organizing a successful take over. And this time he would have his mother full magical arsenal at his back. And fairy godmothers magic is STRONGER than Rumpelstiltskin's as he was unable to reverse Fionas curse, something that Fairy Godmother could do and was her doing in the first place. Unless the Fairy Godmother turned her eyes somewhere else after Harold's death or Rumpelstiltskin got a different deal with her.

So in short. Charming should have absolutely rescued Fiona. But again they stretched themselves too thin and did this movie as a money grab. So... there’s a huge plot hole.

Comment: This is a rant but there is somewhat of an answer in here. Could you [edit] this to take out the rant and focus it more on specifically answering the question?

Answer (score -2):

My theory is in Skrek Forever After, Prince charming wasn't shown because, remember, he came late, probably months later after Fiona was saved by Shrek and they were on their honeymoon after being together for a while.

Charming was probably still at Far Far Away as Fiona was saved. So in Shrek Forever After, Rumpelstiltskin took over Far Far away and he would have dealt with Prince Charming and Fairy Godmother. Remember Rumpelstiltskin is very intelligent, more so than Fairy Godmother and it was probably easy for him to get rid of Charming.

Also in Shrek 2 Prince Charming came back to Far Far Away AFTER Shrek and Fiona visited/lived with the king and queen, and that's when Fairy Godmother, Lillian and Harold found out that the Prince was a little too late to rescue her and that Shrek was the outcome since he is the first to rescue her.

Also without Shrek, Farquad's knights would have died from the dragon and well it definitely was a sacrifice Farquad made and he probably waited a while till he figured one of the knights couldn't rescue her so he chose a different princess.

Another thing I want to be clear on is why Rumpelstiltskin had the fairy tale creatures if Farquad sent them elsewhere.... witches captured them for Rumpelstiltskin when he took over, also the Fairy tale creatures would have ruined the swamp to be a desert... cuz no Shrek, no swamp, it would have been ruined.

Rumpelstiltskin is creating his empire so he needs a lot of people. He ruined the palace so the citizens can sign his contracts to get what they dream since Rumpelstiltskin ruined their dreams and Rumpelstiltskin gets something in return such as Pinocchio, he definitely wanted something from him and he laughed about his evil plan, but obviously he never got it because Shrek always interrupted so he saved Pinocchio unintentionally a few times in the movie.

Comment: Could you [edit] this to include paragraphs to make it more readable?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site Tracey, I did some formatting to your answer. As it stands it's more opinion based than we'd like. To see why that might be, have a long read of some highly upvoted answers on the site, take the [tour] and visit the [help].